# Create action redirects to the wrong page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I check to see if my error message is working correctly, I notice my redirect goes to `/businesses` instead of `/businesses/new` after it POST (`create` action). I am using the regular RESTFUL routes but I need it to go back to `/businesses/new` on POST when their is an error. How can I do this?

---

This is my current code:

```
def create
  @business = Business.new(params[:business])
   if @business.save
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "You have successfully added a new business."
   else
    render :action => 'new', :notice => "Please try again."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not redirect if the validation is failed. Here is what i should do to stay on the same page.

```
def create
  @business = Business.new(params[:business])
  if @business.save
    redirect_to businesses_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: My code is basically the same. Sorry I didn't include it. You can take a look at my code as I've edited my answer.

Comment: Are you sure it went through the else clause?

Comment: Hmmmm. It appears it actually doesn't do that. I wonder how I can get it to on the error? Right now after the POST it stops on `/businesses`.

Comment: You should check the backtrace of the error and see why it ends up like this.

Comment: Well I've noticed that when I put `respond_to do |format|` it does go to the `else` clause but it doesn't render my error partial to see what needs correcting. I'll make a new question to address this. Glad its on the same page though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not a redirection. If you chech the html code generated for your form, you will see something like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/business" 
      class="new_business" id="new_business" method="post">
```

This means that the requested page to load is not the "/business/create" but the "/business". That is why you see it in the browser's address bar. This has nothing to do with your redirection in the create action. There you just render the previous form. This is not an error, it is actually working, maybe a little confusing, but that is not much of a problem, I think. With some javascript you can correct it if really needed.

Comment: Interesting. I do see that on the form (`action="/businesses"`). This is a must since I'm having issues keep my `page_header` partial on the page. Maybe its because I'm using simple form and the simple_form-bootstrap gem, causing it to do this.

Comment: Maybe copy to the answer what you see in your form in the browser.